# WPF MvvM Stack Panel and Grid Overflow

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, mvvm-light, scrollviewer, stackpanel

I have some code I am trying to figure out.  I have a Main Window with 5 Grid columns.  I assign Stack panels to each grid column.  I place a view declaration in each stack panel.  The problem is my User Controls in the views are overflowing and not being affected by the bounds set in Main Window.  Here is some code.

Main.xaml:

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <view:ViewContent></view:ViewContent>
    </StackPanel>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Panel.ZIndex="3" ResizeDirection="Columns" ShowsPreview="True" Width="3">
    </GridSplitter>
</Grid>
```

ViewContent.xaml:

```
<UserControl>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" />
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">
        <ListView Grid.Row="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            //Lots of data goes here and won't work with the scroller.
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

The list view does not scroll.  I want the scroller to only be attached to the list view.  There are also Grid Splitters attached to the columns so that they can be resized horizontally in the main window.

Comment: Remove the StackPanel.

Comment: I switched them all to DockPanels and it works perfectly.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I suggest you delete this question. It's unlikely to help other people in the future.